# mediaelement.js progress disappeared

Tags: mediaelement.js

I just updated my mediaelement-and-player.min.js, jquery.js and flashmediaelement.swf to the files currently on github to try to fix a problem I had with IE9. The problem did dissapear, but so did my progressbar and total time. 
When I look at css with firebug i see:

```
<span class="mejs-time-total" style="width: 0px;">
```

Why does this element all of a sudden get a width of 0?? Disabling this gives me back my progressbar. But I can't seem to find a way to be able to do it from my code.

Comment: the .mejs-time-rail div also gets the same inline style setting the width to 0.

Comment: This just gets weirder, before I updated I got a .mejs-duration span inside the .mejs-time. It has now dissapeared completly. Why?